# How to derive that Optical path length should be stationary from Fermat's principle?

Tags: optics, refraction, variational-principle

I read above eq. (5.3) in "Optics" by Eugene Hecht

> Fermat's Principle maintains that the optical path length OPL will be stationary; that is, its derivative with respect to the position variable will be zero.

I am wondering, how is this derived?

From this post [Derivation of Optical Path Length](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/569138/) we know that

$$cT=ns$$
where $c$ is the speed of light, $T$ is time light takes to travel through the medium, $n$ is refractive index, and $s$ is the distance Light have traveled through the medium.
What is the meaning of position variable in here? Is it just $x$ position? If it is, then does he means that
$$\frac{dcT}{dx}=0 ?$$
Then what is the meaning of this equation, I can't see its relation with Fermat's principle.

Comment: I don't think this is derived, but merely a statement of the principle. If the path length is stationary, this means it won't change with small changes to the path. If we denote the path length $l$ then $\frac{dl}{dx}=0$ That is, for a small variation $dx$ in the path $x$ then the change in the path length $dl=0$.

Comment: I understand! U are my hero!

Comment: Glad to help...

Comment: Related : [Why one should follow Snell's law for shortest time?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/257140/why-one-should-follow-snells-law-for-shortest-time).

Comment: you can derive it from wave optics using the eikonal equation.